# Open source tool to extract data from Temenos T24

Tags: talend, jbase

Is there an open source tool to extract data from a T24 system to a SQL database? Or maybe a connector for Talend?

Thank you

Comment: It's not a SQL database. I'm on a Jbase format and I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is no and no. There is no such open source tool and there is no widely available connector for Talend that I am aware of.

The main issue you have in translating jbase data to SQL is that jbase is not a relational database, and has multi valued fields or groups of fields that do not fit in a relational database, as they are not normalized. Now, in order to connect to jbase and extract info to store in a RDBMS, you would need some kind of api or connector that understands the JEDI. If you check link jbase you will find there is a odbc and a jdbc driver that you can use to connect. But I don't think they are provided free of charge. You have to own jbase database to gain access to them. Alternatively, you could use T24 tool, called DW.EXPORT, to extract information to text format such as csv and then find a way to import that csv to your RDBMS. This is the process used by T24 to export its data to its data warehouse system which uses a relational database.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought but I wasn't sure.

Comment: T24 (Transact) is running on multi value database and this cannot be loaded to RDBMS database directly. We need to write the own logic to break the Multi/Sub values into the required format before loading it to any RDBMS database.